# how to create a dynamic fields using a dynamically created button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, arrays

i am creating one ui in that i am facing this problem please help

i want to create a dynamic fields using dynamically created button by using jQuery.  if your  not understand please check code

jQuery file

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(e){
        var html='<div><br>Alter Mobile No : <input type="text" name="mobile[]" id="mobile">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="button" name="close" value="X" id="cls"></div>';
        var htmlrow ='<br><div style="text-align: left;"><input type="button" name="remrow" id="remrow" value="X"><div class="row"><div>Full Name :<input type="text" name="fname[]" id="fname"></div><div class="col-md-3" id="addmob">Mobile No : <input type="text" name="mobile[]" id="mobile"> &nbsp;<input type="button" name="addB" id="add" value="+" ></div></div></div>';

        $("#add").click(function(){
            $("#addmob").append(html);
        });

        $("#addmob").on('click','#cls',function(e){
            $(this).parent('div').remove();
        }); 

        $("#addrow").click(function(){
            $("#row123").append(htmlrow);
        });

        $("#row123").on('click','#remrow',function(e){
            $(this).parent('div').remove();
        });
    });
</script>
```

html file

```
<body>
    <div>
        <input type="button" name="addrow" id="addrow" value="Add">
    </div>
    <br>
    <div class="container" id="row123">
        <div class="col-md-3">
        Full Name :<input type="text" name="fname" id="lname">
        </div><br>
        <div class="col-md-3" id="addmob">
           Mobile No : <input type="text" name="mobile[]" id="mobile"> &nbsp;<input type="button" name="add" id="add" value="+" >
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: What exactly are you having trouble with?

Comment: i want to create  html text box by using button (that is dynamically created button)

Comment: you can create a button dynamically using PHP script or Jquery, here which button you want dynamically

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function(e){
                var html='<div><br>Alter Mobile No : <input type="text" name="mobile[]" id="mobile">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="button" name="close" value="X" id="cls"></div>';
                var htmlrow ='<div style="text-align: left; margin-top:15px;"><input type="button" name="remrow" id="remrow" value="X"><div class="row"><div>Full Name :<input type="text" name="fname[]" id="fname"></div><div class="col-md-3" id="addmob">Mobile No : <input type="text" name="mobile[]" id="mobile"> &nbsp;<input type="button" name="addB" id="add" value="+" ></div></div></div>';


                $("#row123").on('click', '#add', function(){
                    $(this).closest("#addmob").append(html);
                });


                $("#row123").on('click','#cls',function(e){

                $(this).parent('div').remove();
                   }); 

                $("#addrow").click(function(){


                    $("#row123").append(htmlrow);

                });

                $("#row123").on('click','#remrow',function(e){

                $(this).parent('div').remove();
               });

            });
```